# Writing to char* array in C throws segfault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm an infosec student, who has just begun learning C. I've been given an assignment to write a simple translation program using this prototype: `char* dictionary[number_of_words][2];`.

The output should look something like this:

```
Enter # of words to add: 3

dictionary[0][0]= plane
dictionary[0][1]= Flugzeug
dictionary[1][0]= house
dictionary[1][1]= Haus
dictionary[2][0]= cat
dictionary[2][1]= Katze

Enter english word to translate: house
---> Haus
```

My current (work in progress) code looks like this:

```
void clean_stdin(void);
int main(void)
{
     unsigned int i = 0,j = 0,size; 
     printf("Enter # of words to add: ");
     scanf("%u",&size);
     clean_stdin(); //clears input buffer

     char* dictionary[size][2];

     while(i <= size) 
     {   
         printf("dictionary[%u][%u]= ",i,j);
         fgets(dictionary[i][j],100,stdin);

         if(j >= 1)
         {
             j = 0;
             ++i; 
         }
         else
             j = 1;
         }   

     return 0;
 }
```

The code throws no errors when compiled with `gcc -Wall main.c`, but this is the behaviour I get:

```
Enter # of words to add: 3
dictionary[0][0]= plane
dictionary[0][1]= Flugzeug
dictionary[1][0]= house
dictionary[1][1]= Haus
fish: “./a.out” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Adressbereichsfehler)

*****

Enter # of words to add: 4
dictionary[0][0]= plane
fish: “./a.out” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Adressbereichsfehler)
```

There's a fundamental flaw somewhere in my thought process. Any help/heads up is very appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. And maybe it's time to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: where is memory the memory allocated that the elements of dictionary should be pointing to?

Comment: `dictionary` is `size` number of *array [`2`] pointers to char*. A *pointer* is a variable that stores the address of something else as its value. When you declare a pointer without initializing it to point to something else, it is an *uninitialized pointer*. (it doesn't store the address of anything else). Just like `int a;` declares `a` without a value. A *pointer* points to the *address of* something (i.e. it points to a memory address). You provide that address by assigning the address of a valid block of memory to your pointer, from existing or newly allocated memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this part of your code:

```
char* dictionary[size][2];

 while(i <= size) 
 {   
     printf("dictionary[%u][%u]= ",i,j);
     fgets(dictionary[i][j],100,stdin);
```

Each `dictionary[i][j]` is a pointer to `char`, but you haven't set them to point anywhere meaningful yet - each array element contains some random bit pattern that may or may not correspond to a writable address.  Your first few entries get written *somewhere*, but eventually you try to write to a memory location you don't own or don't have access to.

You will need to set aside additional memory to store each individual string.  You either need create a 3D array of `char` (not `char *`):

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100
...
char dictionary[size][2][MAX_STR_LEN+1];
```

*or* you will need to dynamically allocate memory for each array entry:

```
while ( i < size )  // <, not <=
{
  dictionary[i][j] = malloc( sizeof *dictionary[i][j] * (MAX_STR_LEN + 1));
  if ( !dictionary[i][j] )
  {
    // memory allocation failed, handle error
  }
  printf("dictionary[%u][%u]= ",i,j);
  fgets(dictionary[i][j],MAX_STR_LEN,stdin);
```

If you allocate memory dynamically, you will need to explicitly `free` it when you're done:

```
for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ )
{
  free( dictionary[i][0] );
  free( dictionary[i][1] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of messing around with arrays of multiple dimensions, I suggest you use structures:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int size;
    printf("Enter # of words to add: ");
    if (scanf("%u", &size) != 1)
        return 1; // cannot convert input to integer

#define WORD_MAX_SIZE 100

    struct {
        char word[WORD_MAX_SIZE];
        char translation[WORD_MAX_SIZE];
    } dictionary[size];

    memset(dictionary, 0, sizeof(dictionary));

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("dictionary[%u].word= ", i);
        fgets(dictionary[i].word, WORD_MAX_SIZE, stdin);
        printf("dictionary[%u].translation= ", i);
        fgets(dictionary[i].translation, WORD_MAX_SIZE, stdin);
    }

    // do something with your stuff
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use structures.

Comment: Well, in that case, consider this exercise as an illustration of the kind of code you don't want to write in the future (IMHO, structuring the code is always better than scratching one's head with arrays in 3 dimensions...).
Nevertheless, dura lex sed lex.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets(dictionary[i][j],100,stdin);` reads from an uninitialized variable (`dictionary[i][j]` was never given a value), which has undefined behavior.

Also, `i` is going out of bounds later.

Comment: actually fgets does not read from dictionary, it writes to the memory pointed to by dictionary which is even worse.

Comment: @DaleWilson I'm not saying `fgets` is doing the reading. I'm saying the expression reads from the variable in order to get the value to pass to the function.